# Google apps script Change size of radio button

Tags: css, google-apps-script, radio-button

I want to change size of radio button using CSS in Google apps script for deploying as web page

I tried this attributes but not changing radio button size

```
    function doGet(){
       var width            = 100;
       var height           = 100;
       var appWidth         = 990;
       var appHeight        = 1400;
       var radio_attributes = {"fontSize":"4em","height":"200%","width":"200%","display":"inline- block")};
       var app              = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(appWidth).setHeight(appHeight);
       var panel            = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("panel").setWidth(appWidth).setHeight(appHeight);
       var radio            = app.createRadioButton("radioButton", "test").setFormValue('test').setHeight(height).setWidth(width).setStyleAttributes(radio_attributes);
       panel.add(radio);
       app.add(panel);
       return app;}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Css , you must create other Script on your project.
for example :

css.gs :

```
var css={};
css.title = {  width : '660px',  
 paddingTop :'10px',
margin:' -12px -11px -10px',
background : 'white',   
 color : '#093B65',
textAlign : 'center',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  borderRadius: '5px',
  border: '2px solid #2081D4'
};
```

And for you Code:

Code.gs

```
 var panelTitle = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes(css.title);
```

Comment: This CSS will affect panel only and I want CSS to change size of radio button to be compatible with word test linked to radio button.

Comment: Yes it's my example but you can add css on radioButton.

Comment: I don't know how to adjust CSS for radio button if you can give me example it will be great

Answer (score 0):

Css button

```
css.button = {  width : '100px',  height : '30px',  fontWeight: 'bold',  borderRadius: '10px',  background : 'blue',  color: 'white'};
```

And my button

```
var button = app.createSubmitButton('submit').setEnabled(true).setStyleAttributes(css.button);
```

This example can help you ?